# Get Excel data range using oledb in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to get excel sheet used data range by using oledb.
Code is below,

```
String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                                    + "Data Source=E:\\DOTNET\\CrsMicro\\CA.xls;"
                                    + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";


using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn))
        {
            string selectString = "SELECT * FROM [CA$A1:D500]";
            using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand(selectString,connExcel))
            {
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
                connExcel.Open();
                DataTable dt=new DataTable();                    
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                adp.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                adp.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
                adp.Fill(dt);
                int range=dt.Columns.Count;
                int row = dt.Rows.Count;

            //var result = cmdExcel.ExecuteReader();

            //DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            //dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
           // string excelsheetname = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            connExcel.Close();
            //string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

my sheet range is not always A1:D500, it may vary frequently. So i need to get the sheet range dynamically. I know this can be achieved by interop, but i need to do it in oledb. Any suggestion?

Comment: you can use VSTO ( Visual Studio Tools for Office) and query Excel for   a selected range, or popup an input box asking the user for some range. VSTO works with Interop

Comment: Let me understand, if you know the ranges it is simply a matter of replacing dynamically the _A1:D500_ with the actual range required. The code above doesn't seem to be wrong.

Comment: I can see reasons against using Interop, but there are so many pitfalls in using the OLEDB drivers (file types, only works for uniform tables, bizarre row type guessing).  I'd suggest looking at managed alternatives like *OpenXML SDK* (for xlsx) or something like https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: If you just use the sheet name, followed by "$", that will return the used range, e.g., `SELECT * FROM [CA$]`

Comment: Yeah i need to know the range, based on that i need to generate sql query dynamically for other puepose. @Doug yeah select * from [ca$] will get uses range. But i need to do based on range wise for few business logic.

Comment: That's sounds like a problematic design. Good luck!

Comment: To be clear for you i want to use sql command in ssis to get excel data, and load it into single oledb destination. If i  have so many columns in excel i will use union all to make that single column. Thats why i want to know range

Answer (score 0):

create a named range:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196817.aspx
and replace `selectString` to

```
"SELECT * FROM [CA$MyNamedRange]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm also working on same kind of problem in OLEDB C# excel, I found below solution. It works for me. But I'm new to C#, I'm not sure how efficient it is. 
But it is satisfying my requirements so far.  This may be helpful for others.

I was able to get dynamic range in an excel sheet from a browsed input excel file (make sure excel file doesn't contain hidden sheets). This works perfectly for excel workbook containing single sheet. I haven't tested with multiple sheets.

Range:  A [stat value]: Column Name[0] // Returns all rows from start value till the column name.
Example: A1:M0  // It will return all rows from A1 till column M. So here no need to worry how many rows you have in your excel. 
Just by giving Column Name[0] takes all rows from the starting till the column M.
So '0' will be our outer range.

```
//Code under actual c# clas file where we are uploading excel.
Excel_Common excelComm = new Excel_Common(); // object to Excel_Common class file

string rangeStringwithSHeet =excelComm.GetSheetName(filepath).ToString().Trim('\'') + GetRange(excelComm.GetSheetName(filepath), excelComm.ExcelConn(filepath));

queryForExcelInput = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", rangeStringwithSHeet);

Econ1 = new OleDbConnection(excelComm.ExcelConn(filepath));
Econ1.Open();
dataExcelInputTable = new DataTable();
OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new OleDbCommand(queryForExcelInput, Econ1);
OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDaAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleDbCommand1);
oleDbDaAdapter1.Fill(dataExcelInputTable);
```

## Excel_Common class file has below methods:

```
//Get Range like A4:M30

    public string GetRange(string SheetName, string excelConnectionString)
   {
        string rangeInput = "",rangeColName="";
        int columnsCount = 0;
        int rowStartRange = 0;

        columnsCount = GetNumberOfColumnsInSheet(SheetName, excelConnectionString);
        rowStartRange = GetStartRowRange(SheetName, excelConnectionString); // This is optional if you want always A1. just assign 1 here 
        while (columnsCount > 0)
        {
            columnsCount--;
            rangeColName = (char)('A' + columnsCount % 26) + rangeColName;
            columnsCount /= 26;
        }

        rangeInput = "A" + rowStartRange + ":" + rangeColName + "0";



        return rangeInput;
    }



// Get Sheet Name assuming only one sheet for workbook and no hidden sheets
 public string GetSheetName(string filepath)
 {
 string sheetname = "";
 String connect = ExcelConn(filepath);
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect);
 con.Open();

 DataTable tables = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

        foreach (DataRow row in tables.Rows)
        {
            sheetname = row[2].ToString();
            if (!sheetname.EndsWith("$"))
                continue;

        }

  con.Close();
  return sheetname;
 }


// Get number of columns in a given sheet
    public int GetNumberOfColumnsInSheet(string SheetName, string excelConnectionString)
    {
        int columnsCount = 0;

        //If a valid excel file
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelConnectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                columnsCount = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == SheetName).Count();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return columnsCount;
    }


// Get the first row count in sheet contains some keyword . This method call is optional if you always want A1. Here I need to check some keyword exist and from there only I have to start something like A4


public int GetStartRowRange(string SheetName, string excelConnectionString)
 {
     int rowStartRange = 1;

     //If a valid excel file
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelConnectionString))
     {
         using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
         {
             string colValue;
             conn.Open();
             string cmdstr = "select * from [" + SheetName + "]";

             OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, conn);
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
             da.Fill(dt);



             // get first row data where it started

             foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
             {

                 colValue = dataRow[0].ToString();


                 if ((colValue.Contains("Value1") || colValue.Contains("Value2") || colValue.Contains("Value3")) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRow[1].ToString()) == false))
                 {
                     rowStartRange = rowStartRange + 1;
                     break;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     rowStartRange = rowStartRange + 1;
                 }

             }

             conn.Close();


         }

     }
     return rowStartRange;
 }


// Connection to excel document
public string ExcelConn(string FilePath)
{
    string constr = "";
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FilePath);

    //Checking for the extentions, if XLS connect using Jet OleDB
    if (extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES\"", FilePath);
    }
    //Use ACE OleDb if xlsx extention
    else if (extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES\"", FilePath);
    }


    return constr;

} // end of ExcelConn method
```